# Setting time to 00:00:00 on all the dates

Tags: sql, database

I have a table with 100 records in which there is one column that is storing date having values like:

```
10-04-2016 10:20:00
12-05-2016 13:09:00
```

I want to update all the dates and set the time as `00:00:00`, i.e.

```
10-04-2016 00:00:00
12-05-2016 00:00:00
```

Comment: And your DB engine is which one?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: ANSI SQL: `update t set c = cast(cast(c as date) as timestamp)`

Comment: @jarh update t set c = cast(cast(c as date) as timestamp) does not works :(

Comment: So which dbms are you using? You need a product specific answer here!

Comment: Why do you want to do it? And in which RDBMS?

Comment: `does not works` is no help, to us or to yourself.  In what way doesn't it work?  Do you get an error message, and if so what exact message do you get?  Do you get results you don't expect?  If so, what was your input, what was your output and what was the output you expected?

Comment: script was executed but I still get the time on the date. I am using Oracle 11 DB

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, following would work:

```
DECLARE @input DATETIME = '2016-05-11 13:17:41.410'

SELECT DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1 * DATEPART(MILLISECOND,@input), DATEADD(SECOND, -1 * DATEPART(SECOND, @input), DATEADD(MINUTE, -1 * DATEPART(MINUTE, @input), DATEADD(HOUR, -1 * DATEPART(HOUR, @input), @input)))) as NewDate, @input as InputDate
```

Comment: `DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @input), 0)` is a bit more concise, or even `CAST(@input AS DATE)`, ever since that data type was introduced.